# Rspec: Is there a way do execute code after the before(:each) block but before the actual it-block?

Tags: ruby, rspec, configuration

I am trying to write a tool to measure the amount of http requests our feature specs make (if they make 0 we can move them over to a less expensive javascript spec).

The problem I'm having is that I do not want to recognize requests made in the before(:each) block. I want to set my counts variable to 0 after the before(:each) block has been executed but before the 'it-block' has been executed.

Right now the code looks something like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:each) do |test|
    HTTPSpec::Counts= 0 
  end

  WebMock.after_request do |request_signature, response|
    HTTPSpec::Counts += 1 
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hack that might work for you:

```
require 'rspec'

$should_get_reset = 0
$should_not_get_reset = 0

# monkey-patch :before
module RSpec::Core::Hooks
    alias_method :original_before, :before
    def before(*args, &block)
        original_before *args do
            block.call
            $should_get_reset = 0
        end
    end

    # Alias :append_before to the new :before, because they do it here:
    # https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/9f99b6aa24e24edd530035868e258abd24d88385/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb#L201
    alias_method :append_before, :before
end

describe "Hi" do
    before do
        $should_get_reset = 1
        $should_not_get_reset = 1
    end

    it "mom" do
        $should_get_reset += 1
        $should_not_get_reset += 1
        expect($should_get_reset).to eq(1)
        expect($should_not_get_reset).to eq(2)
    end
end
```

You can save this in a file (say `foo_spec.rb`) and run `rspec foo_spec.rb` to see it work.  In practice, you would want to move your monkey-patching to a spec helper or support file.

Comment: really cool idea! However, it seems that block.call is throwing off the scope of the block because I'm getting undefined method errors.